# Task Scheduler creates a unhandled exception

Tags: c#

I have created a .NET console app that reads arguments from a .txt file as the arguments can get rather long if need be. So this application works fine when you run it manually. The issue I am having is when I set it up in the task scheduler, once it triggers and runs I get a unhandled exception relating to System.IO.FileNotFound, this was found in the event viewer.

Question is, why it fails using task scheduler and works fine manually?

The task is run as domain\admin and also changed the argument security for everyone to have full access.

Comment: Which user account are you running the scheduled task, does it have permissions to the file?

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFound` How does the app open the file? If you are using a relative path, that's using the current working directory which is probably not what you expect when being run from task scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It runs as Domain\Admin and I have changed the security on the arguments.txt file for everyone to have full access. I have modified the app to take the arguments.txt as a full relative path rather than just a file in the same directory as app. Unfortunately all has failed so far

Comment: Since you have no code here, and since the code nominally works fine except in a specific Windows scenario, this is really more of a superuser.stackexchange.com question than a SO question. But even in the context of this site, it's a duplicate, as your exception is simply due to you using the wrong path in your code (i.e. a working directory that's not what you assumed). There are a variety of ways to deal with this; e.g. you can specify the path explicitly, or configure the task to use the working directory you assumed. See duplicate.

Comment: Solution was to add the working folder when using the Task Scheduler. Changing it to the full path did not fix my problem. I am going to leave this up rather than deleting it, google had no answers to this, that I could fins anyway. Any suggestions for changing the title maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to specify the correct starting folder in the Task Scheduler to make sure that the system has access to all the required files.

In the Task Scheduler when you specify the path of your program to run, also insert the path to the folder your program is located in the "start in" field (see screenshot below)…

[image: here is a screenshot]

Comment: Not sure where my comment went from here? Thank you, this was a fix for my issue. Adding the folder path to "Start in (optional):" fixed the issue and the app now works as predicted.

Comment: I was having the same problem, searching for hours why it was not working... Thank you !

Comment: I had the same issue this solution works for me. Thumbs up